# Python standalone file with xgboost package

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, py2exe, xgboost

I am building an app with machine learning model using xgboost. I am trying to build a standalone exe file in windows using Python 3.5

I've used pyinstaller, using the 
    pyinstall mycode.py 
it creates a dist but this is the error that I get in the end:

> "    win32api.EndUpdateResource(hdst, 0) pywintypes.error: (5,
>   'EndUpdateResource', 'Access is denied.')"

Other modules I've used are datetime, csv, tkinter, and numpy.

Hope you can recommend step-by-step instructions on how I can make my program a standalone exe application using any compiler that can do the job.

TIA.

Comment: Is that error what you get when you run pyinstaller or what you get when you run the built app?